# USB connected device is not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

For the past week or so my Android device which is connected via USB is not listed in Android Studio so I am unable to get the logcat messages nor can I terminate the app.

From Android Studio it detects that my device is plugged in but in the Android tab it does not list the app so I am unable to click it and then click terminate.

Anyone know how I fix this?

Comment: Do you see the device in terminal using the command 'adb devices'? if not, then it's not a problem with Android Studio, but with adb not able to find your device

Comment: I revoked access for the app to my device and then enabled it again. I think it was due to an upgrade to 5.1

Answer (score -1):

**Check  device manager**
Other device / mobile device problem on driver installation
Install this https://www.mediafire.com/file/eizx5mpwt6zb9f6/adbdriver.zip/file
Then go to check adb device install problem
At last install this https://adbdriver.com/downloads/
File in google drive also
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OS5bFg5sIRaqUslzGtnrk0QwoD3Qptfa/view?usp=sharing
At last success in mobile name display in android Studio
Once again check in device manager in portable device - show mobile name

Comment: Please do not suggest links pointing to unsafe resources like mediafire or google drive. Nobody will blindly download from these (hopefully). You should use the official links instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30362855)